# Detecting whether the signal is increasing intensity or decreasing intensity

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, wavelet, signal-detection, audio-processing

I am trying to determine whether the signal is increasing intensity, decreasing intensity, fade-in, fade-out or peak using an audio file. The graph has an x-axis with time and a y-axis with the data. I am a bit stuck about how to move ahead as should I take the timeframe and calculate the peaks or should I use amplitude or set a threshold value to detect.
How can I proceed with detecting the intensity or fading using python?

Comment: Do you know anything about the signal or the noise it is in (if any)? Is the signal a single tone with varied amplitude, or is it a mixture of tones, or is it random?

Comment: Do you have to do that in an instance-base (per sample, or pair of samples), for a frame, for a whole audio file? What exactly is the task? How do you define the difference between increasing intensity and fade-in or decreasing intensity and fade-out? What do you mean by "peak"?